# Row and column ID's in tables

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, calendar

I have a strange problem that I'm trying to figure out.  I'm making a timesheet, and I'm supposed to "import" our time off of a calendar into it.

I'm thinking I would have to make the row with the days in it the header row or table head.  Would I name each column?

Example:

This is my time sheet

[image: timesheet]

So lets say I'm taking off March 1st for vacation (which is a thursday, and would be in the 2nd week).  So, it would be under column 12 - "thursday".

I would want it to to automatically put in 8 hours in the cell for vacation row/ column 12 / Thursday.

I'm not quite sure about how to set up, and then execute.  Setting up is bigger issue at the moment.  I have the table set up, but I'm thinking I will need to make adjustments to accommodate columns names and such.  I'll be using C# to do all calculations and filling in and all that jazz.  Do the table in the aspx page.  As far as formatting, I can post the code if you want to see, though it is quite large.

1st question:  How do I create a table header row that has ID's?

2nd question:  Same thing, but for the rows?

Ties into 3rd question: If I have a specific date, I want to place in a specific spot in the table.  How do I do that?

Any advice or ideas will help

Comment: What is your question? You are going to have to be more clear and specific.

Comment: well 1st question is how to create a table header row that has id's?
2nd question is the same for the rows?
ties into 3rd question..if i have a specific date..i want to place in a specific spot in the table..how do i do that?

Comment: You should likely be using a GridView bound to some underlying data source. Instead of trying to set the values of the cells directly, you could just update the data source.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Alright I will add an answer with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should likely be using a GridView bound to some underlying data source. For example:

Create your GridView in aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="TimeSheetGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday1" HeaderText="Sunday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday1" HeaderText="Monday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday1" HeaderText="Tuesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday1" HeaderText="Wednesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday1" HeaderText="Thursday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday1" HeaderText="Friday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday1" HeaderText="Saturday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday2" HeaderText="Sunday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday2" HeaderText="Monday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday2" HeaderText="Tuesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday2" HeaderText="Wednesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday2" HeaderText="Thursday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday2" HeaderText="Friday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday2" HeaderText="Saturday" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Create a class to hold the information:

```
class TimeSheetItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Sunday1 { get; set; }
    public int Monday1 { get; set; }
    public int Tuesday1 { get; set; }
    public int Wednesday1 { get; set; }
    public int Thursday1 { get; set; }
    public int Friday1 { get; set; }
    public int Saturday1 { get; set; }

    public int Sunday2 { get; set; }
    public int Monday2 { get; set; }
    public int Tuesday2 { get; set; }
    public int Wednesday2 { get; set; }
    public int Thursday2 { get; set; }
    public int Friday2 { get; set; }
    public int Saturday2 { get; set; }
}
```

Devise a method to retrieve your information somehow (from database etc). Here is what I did as an example:

```
private List<TimeSheetItem> GetData()
{
    return new List<TimeSheetItem>()
    {
         new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN1" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN2" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN3" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN4" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Personal" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Doctor" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Other" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Sick" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Vacation", Thursday2 = 8 } // Put in your 8 hours
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Holiday" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Meeting" }
    };
}
```

Bind the data to your GridView in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TimeSheetGrid.DataSource = GetData();
        TimeSheetGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

That should give you something like this, which you can style however you want using CSS.

[image: Time Sheet Example]

### Edit

In order to allow the user to edit the data in this grid you have a couple options. One would be to use a datasource that supports default editing. You can read more on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czzytf25%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can also add editing manually. To do that you need to make some changes to the GridView:

1. Add an OnRowEditing event that will turn on editing for a row
2. Add an OnRowUpdating event that will update your datasource
3. Add an OnRowCancelingEdit event that will cancel the edit mode
4. Add a DataKey so we can know which row we are editing
5. Add a CommandField with an Edit button
6. Set your primary key column (Name in this case) to ReadOnly

Your GridView would now look like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="TimeSheetGrid" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    onrowediting="TimeSheetGrid_RowEditing" 
    onrowupdating="TimeSheetGrid_RowUpdating"
    DataKeyNames="Name" onrowcancelingedit="TimeSheetGrid_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday1" HeaderText="Sunday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday1" HeaderText="Monday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday1" HeaderText="Tuesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday1" HeaderText="Wednesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday1" HeaderText="Thursday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday1" HeaderText="Friday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday1" HeaderText="Saturday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday2" HeaderText="Sunday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday2" HeaderText="Monday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday2" HeaderText="Tuesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday2" HeaderText="Wednesday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday2" HeaderText="Thursday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday2" HeaderText="Friday" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday2" HeaderText="Saturday" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In your code-behind your code would have to look something like this. Note that I am using the Session object to persist the data.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["TimeSheetItems"] = GetData();
        BindData();
    }
}

protected void TimeSheetGrid_RowCancelingEdit(
     object sender
    ,GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    // Exit edit mode - the user clicked cancel
    TimeSheetGrid.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}

protected void TimeSheetGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    // Enter edit mode - the user clicked edit
    TimeSheetGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void TimeSheetGrid_RowUpdating(
     object sender
    ,GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var items = (IEnumerable<TimeSheetItem>)Session["TimeSheetItems"];

    // Get the TimeSheetItem that was being edited
    var item = items.Single(i => i.Name.Equals(e.Keys["Name"].ToString()));

    // Set the TimeSheetItem values to the new values
    item.Sunday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Sunday1"]);
    item.Monday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Monday1"]);
    item.Tuesday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Tuesday1"]);
    item.Wednesday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Wednesday1"]);
    item.Thursday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Thursday1"]);
    item.Friday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Friday1"]);
    item.Saturday1 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Saturday1"]);
    item.Sunday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Sunday2"]);
    item.Monday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Monday2"]);
    item.Tuesday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Tuesday2"]);
    item.Wednesday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Wednesday2"]);
    item.Thursday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Thursday2"]);
    item.Friday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Friday2"]);
    item.Saturday2 = TryGetIntValue(e.NewValues["Saturday2"]);

    // Exit from edit mode
    TimeSheetGrid.EditIndex = -1;

    // Re-bind the data
    BindData();
}

private static int TryGetIntValue(object val)
{
    int intVal;
    Int32.TryParse(val.ToString(), out intVal);
    return intVal;
}

private void BindData()
{
    TimeSheetGrid.DataSource = Session["TimeSheetItems"];
    TimeSheetGrid.DataBind();
}

private IEnumerable<TimeSheetItem> GetData()
{
    // You can pre-populate the hours here
    return new List<TimeSheetItem>()
    {
         new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN1" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN2" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN3" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "IN4" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Personal" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Doctor" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Other" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Sick" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Vacation", Thursday2 = 8 }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Holiday" }
        ,new TimeSheetItem() { Name = "Meeting" }
    };
}
```

You can pre-populate the hours in the GetData method by setting the values in the TimeSheetItems, or in whatever method you are using to retrieve your data.

This is just a brief example of one way you could accomplish this. You should read up more on the basics of ASP.NET, C# and the GridView control.

Comment: ok...this is a lot less code so i like it..thank you...2 quick questions about it
1. so lets say i had a variable that had everything i needed to autofill a holiday..like wednesday2 - doctor..how would i tell the table to put the data right there under wed2 in the doctor row?
2. How do you edit the fields?

Comment: @EddyWhitaker Does the user require the ability to edit the values through this screen, or are you just pre-populating the values to display to the user?

Comment: preferably editing through this screen..currently we have an excel spreadsheet where they do it, so i'm trying to keep it as similar as possible because they dont handle change well haha..but if they have vacation and doctors and such if they happend to have one of those days..i'd like it to pre-populate

Comment: @EddyWhitaker I will add an example for what you are trying to do, but this will only be a start. You should really read up on the basics of the ASP.NET GridView [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx).

Comment: ok..thanks for all the help..i put all the code in ..and got "Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode." ..but i'll play around with that..see if i cant figure it out

Comment: Adding the `Serializable` attribute to the class you are using to store the data might fix that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5889429/199220) answer.

Comment: It did fix it the first time, then when i refreshed the page it gave me "Unable to find assembly 'App_Web_o04uwj24, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."  .. Also i definitely need to do more research on this serialization as i have never dealt with it before

Comment: What kind of objects are you trying to store in the session? Are they anonymous objects returned from a LINQ query? If so I don't think you are going to be able to do that, you will have to store them in a concrete class just as I have in my example. If you are already doing that then I am not sure what the problem is. You don't have to store them in the Session at all though, you could pull them straight from the data store (database etc) for every databind if that will work.

Comment: I mean i literally copied your code because it seems to work(still looking at all the stff with asp.net gridview)..and added the serialiaze part..to be honest.. i dont need to really store in session i dont think..(still new to the whole session/serialization thing) ..it doesnt bother me that i would be pulling them straight from the database...seems more logical to me...really my biggest problem is still..if someone has a sick day...having it know exactly where to put it..i saw it in your code..but thats hardcoded in there..especially if they have multiple days off in a week/2 week period

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your problem. You would just populate the objects as you are creating them from the information from the database. You could get a specific item by name using LINQ: `item  = items.Single(i => i.Name.Equals('Doctor');` and then set the values in that object to whatever you want: `item.Friday1 = 4;`. You can do that however you want, that is very basic C#. Please let me know if I am misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: i'm probably not doing the best job of explaining it..let me try this..the idea of this time sheet is to be able to store on computer and use existing date to save the user time..so ideally..the only rows the user is editing are the first 4..any reasons for not  being at work are populated automatically..and then (i didnt show this section, all the data is calculated)..we have a table in our database just for time off..so thats where it would be pulled from..so lets say i'm off friday 1 and mon2...when i "submit" my time sheet..i wont have to edit those columns, they will already be done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8308/discussion-between-kevev22-and-eddy-whitaker)