# ASP.NET Session has expired or could be found in SharePoint 2007

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to load an .rdlc file in SharePoint 2007 but it is not getting loaded and the following error is coming on that Report Page.

Below mentioned is the code which I've used.
Kindly help what modifications I should have to do.

```
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.EnableViewState = true;

        rptViewer.Reset();
        rptViewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
        rptViewer.KeepSessionAlive = true;
        rptViewer.EnableViewState = true;
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\New folder\RDLC\RiskReports\RiskReports\Report1.rdlc";
    }
```

It would be a great help and appreciation.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492677/asp-net-session-has-expired-or-could-not-be-found-because-the-session-session

Comment: It's not like. I've seen it already.

Comment: Have you tried to change KeepSessionAlive to false and AsyncRendering to False?? and what is the Session storage mode you are using???

Comment: Now it throwing this error :

"A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'."