# Stateful experience 7 comparison of ways to maintain state

Tags: asp.net, session

My company has a 3rd party web service we are designing a front end for. The "objects" used by this web service are very large (and variable depending on the number of sub-entities created). The web service does not expose methods to commit/load sub-entities, only the full object hierarchy.

The UI itself is split into many sub screens, and master/detail views to be able to efficiently/easily edit the large amount of data.

The issue is where to store all the data you aren't currently looking at.

Doing the web service commit takes up to 30 seconds for large records, so it is not feasible to use the web service for the intermittent data storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using .Net's SessionState out of the box, with the [SQL persistence mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx) to cache the web service data, although you do need to ensure that you have a strategy to clear out expired data from the database. All objects stored in SessionState will need to be [Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889240/unable-to-serialize-the-session-state).

Also, instead of using the external web service's entity structure (e.g. the serializable proxy entities generated by a .Net added Service Reference), you should also 
consider building your own customized class hierarchy for your screens (i.e. custom view models), and then build the bridging to map / project the web service graph to your viewmodel after the initial fetch from the web service, and then back again to the web service entities after the user has finished updating the graph. LINQ is great for this purpose, or possibly [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), if you haven't deviated from the web service class and property naming standards.