# Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serialization

I am trying to implement StateServer Session management for my asp.net application.I came to know that every object n my session need to be serializable.

for that i have added **Serializable** tag to every class. But it is showing above error message.I then tried Linq-To-Sql feature in order that at least object will be serialized. But it also did not work. what possibly should i do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to serialize the session state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889240/unable-to-serialize-the-session-state)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're putting something in session that isn't serializable (as you suspect).

Since you've marked your own classes as `Serializable` there are a couple of likely possibilities:

1. You've inherited from something that isn't `Serializable` (so marking your inherited class `Serializable` won't help).
2. You're attempting to store something in session that isn't one of your classes, and isn't serializable, most likely a framework class. Common examples might be `EntitySet`, `DataTable` or `Dictionary<>`.

Also the exact class that is causing the problem should be clear from the full exception info.

For example the following is in the error message shown in the question I've [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889240/unable-to-serialize-the-session-state):

```
[SerializationException: Type 'Gebruiker' in Assembly 'App_Code.qzuhycmn, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
```

Comment: Yes this is the frame work class System.Data.Linq.DataContext. Actual Error : SerializationException: Type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq. WHAT SHOULD I DO IN ORDER TO IMPLEMENT "STATESERVER".

Comment: Don't store DataContext in session (this is very likely to be a bad plan anyway). Store the results you use to build your pages in state, but structural stuff like DataContext - that should be fresh for each Unit Of Work ideally.

Comment: I am not storing DataContext in Session,actually a class is stored which inherits the DataContext.Can there be any possible way to store that object do you need to mention in dbml(i read a doc. saying you need to add <DataBase .... Serialization=UniDirectional>) but i am confused where to add it.

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/11/27/linq-to-sql-enabling-dbml-file-for-wcf.aspx) - In the designer, right click in empty space (not on an entity) and select properties.