# Using Session in SQL mode and Json Return Null in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, session

In our MVC application , We are using session in SQL mode.

The issue is while using json, it is returning null values.

Code is

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: "POST",
    url: "ShowReports",
    data: JSON.stringify(ElementDatas),
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        if ((result.message != "")
            {
             }      
        }
```

controller.cs

```
public ActionResult ShowReports(ElementDatas elements)
{
    return Json(new { message = message});
}
```

Suppose if we are using session in proc mode, then json returning values.
Please help..

Comment: I am sorry but your code makes no sense....could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: It might be serialization issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889240/unable-to-serialize-the-session-state

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "Home/ShowReports", 
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({elements: elements}),
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
                if (result.message != ""){ }                    
            }
```

first fix the your URL , parameter sending names must be the same.

You can find and fix here;
[Pass Multiple Parameters to jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916309/pass-multiple-parameters-to-jquery-ajax-call)